# Need help bootstrap uploading image with file name?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

have this code  but this code dont show me also the file name it is possible also show the file name sry new want only upload image and show me the image name over the image??

```
<div class="row">
       <?php 
        //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly
       $folder = "uploads";
       $results = scandir('uploads');
       foreach ($results as $result) {

        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_file($folder . '/' . $result)) {
            echo '
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="'.$folder . '/' . $result.'" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                        <p><a href="remove.php?name='.$result.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Remove</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
       }
       ?>
    </div>
```

- See more at: http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php_file_upload_tutorial_part_2#sthash.Mgxy3lQA.dpuf`

Comment: I can't read this... Can you correct your english? and links that aren't considered "immortal" should not be linked. add those details into the question instead of linking us to it

Comment: @rayleigh - If im not wrong what you want is simply - While uploading a file, you need to show the name of the file uploaded as well next to it ... Right ?

Comment: yes right want to show the uploaded file name